# Creating HTML table dynamically with some complexity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Below is my **json structure**:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "Variant": "V1",
      "Id": 1,
      "TestList": [
        {
          "SubVariantList": [
            {
              "Id": 10,
              "Name": "A",
             "Fluctuation":100
            },
            {
              "Id": 20,
              "Name": "B",
              "Fluctuation":100
            },
            {
              "Id": 30,
              "Name": "C",
              "Fluctuation":200
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
     "Variant": "V2",
      "Id": 2,
      "TestList": [
        {
          "SubVariantList": [
            {
              "Id": 40,
              "Name": "A",
              "Fluctuation":1100
            },
            {
              "Id": 50,
              "Name": "B",
             "Fluctuation":1200
            },
            {
              "Id": 60,
              "Name": "C",
              "Fluctuation":1300
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Variant": "V3",
      "Id": 3,
      "TestList": [
        {
          "SubVariantList": [
            {
              "Id": 40,
              "Name": "A",
              "Fluctuation":500
            },
            {
              "Id": 50,
              "Name": "C",
              "Fluctuation":600
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now with json structure I have 2 below travels:

```
V1:A - B  - C
V2:A - C
```

Based on above json structure I am creating dynamic table like below:

```
Table1:
                A  -  B            |   B - C (Headers)
VariantName    AValue   BValue         CValue (Columns)
    V1          100     100            200
    V2          1100    1200           1300

Table2: 
A  -  C (Headers)
VariantName    AValue  CValue      (columns)
V3             500     600
```

I will always have subvariants in fixed order starting from 1 point like below:

```
A - B  - C  - D
```

**First A** will be fixed, and rest I can have combinations like this:

```
A - B - C - D
A - B - C
A - C
A-  D
A - B - C - D
A - B - C 
A - D
A-  C
```

Problem comes with some combinations of subvariants flow like below:

```
V1: A - B - C 
V2 : A - B - C - D
```

With above data I am getting table structure like this:

```
Table1 : <thead>
 A - B  |  B - C 

Table2:<thead>
A  -  B  | B - C  | C - D
```

But already A - B and B - C structure is created in table as sequence is right so there will be only 1 table like below:

```
Table1 : <thead>
 A - B  |  B - C  | C - D
```

New table will be created only when there will be jumping like below:

```
A - C
A - D
```

This is my code:

```
<div>
    @{
        var tableHeaders = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            var subvariants = string.Join(",", Model[i].TestList[0].SubVariantList.Select(cd => cd.Name)); //creating unique combination
            if (tableHeaders.Count == 0)
            {
                tableHeaders.Add(subvariants);
            }
            else if (!tableHeaders.Contains(subvariants))
            {
                tableHeaders.Add(subvariants);
            }
        }
    }
    @for (int i = 0; i < tableHeaders.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] subvariants = tableHeaders[i].Split(',');
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @for (int cnt = 0; cnt < tableHeaders.Count() - 1; cnt++) // for 2 subvariants
                    {
                        <td>
                            @subvariants[cnt] <span>-</span>  @subvariants[cnt + 1]
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th style="border: 1px solid black;">VariantName</th>
                    @for (int cnt = 0; cnt < subvariants.Count() - 1; cnt++) 
                   {
                      if (cnt == 0)
                      {
                            <th style="border: 1px solid black;">@subvariants[cnt]</th>
                      }
                        <th style="border: 1px solid black;">@subvariants[cnt + 1]</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @for (int m = 0; m < Model.Count; m++)
                {
                    string subvariants = string.Join(",", Model[m].TestList[0].SubVariantList.Select(cd => cd.Name));
                    var headers = tableHeaders[i];
                    if (headers.Contains(subvariants))
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Model[m].Variant</td>
                            <td>@Model[m].TestList[0].SubVariantList[0].Value</td>
                            @for (int j = 1; j < Model[m].TestList[0].SubVariantList.Count; j++)
                            {
                                <td>@Model[m].TestList[0].SubVariantList[j].Value</td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }

</div>
```

I wonder if I am stuck in this complex logic because of various scenarios and combination of subvariants.

Comment: @StephenMuecke:First of all thank you so much for showing your interest in my question.For subvariants i have a flow like: A - B - C - D  etc.If you will see my subvariants list in json structure i have i would always have subvariants flow from always A- B-C or A - C or A- D etc and yes you are right i mean V1 and not variant1.i guess there is a typo mistake.V1 has A,B,C(json structure)  i want to have headers in table like A-B | B - C to show a flow that A to B and B to C and V3 has A and C that means A to C

Comment: So in the code snippet under _First A will be fixed..._ are you wanting it so that from that list, you will create only 3 tables - `A - B - C - D` and `A - C` and `A - D`?

Comment: And can you have a sequence like `B - D`, and if so, would you need a table for that also?

Comment: @StephenMuecke : In the snippet first A will always be fixed so that means that subvariant list will have have first record which will be starting point for subvaraiant(For Eg:A).I cant have a sequence like B- D unless B is the starting point.If starting point is A then i cant have this B - D variation.So common sequence there will be single table with multiple headers

Comment: @StephenMuecke:New table will be created only in case of new unique variantion like A- C,A -D(I.e when subvariants are jumping from 1 to 3rd or 1st to 4th,1st to 5th etc..)

Comment: OK, the first thing you need to do is get rid of all that logic fro the view and put in the controller (and use a view model to represent what you need in the view). What is the current model in the view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127348/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-learning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to (1) remove all that logic from the view and place it in the controller where it belongs, and (2) use view models to represent how you want to display the data in the view.

Your view models should be

```
public class TableVM
{
    public TableVM()
    {
        Variants = new List<RowVM>();
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Headers { get; set; }
    public List<RowVM> Variants { get; set; }
    // The following properties are used for 'grouping' your data
    public string Sequence { get; set; }
    public bool IsSequential { get; set; }
    public int MaxColumns { get; set; }
}
public class RowVM
{
    public RowVM()
    {
        Fluctuations = new List<ColumnVM>();
    }
    public string Variant { get; set; }
    public List<ColumnVM> Fluctuations { get; set; }
}
public class ColumnVM
{
    public decimal Fluctuation { get; set; }
}
```

which allows you to use simple loops in the view to generate each table, and within each table, a row for each `Variant`, and for each row, a column for each `Fluctuation`.

```
@model List<TableVM>
@foreach(var table in Model)
{
    <h4>@table.Title</h4>
    @foreach(var row in table.Variants)
    {
        <td>@row.Variant</td>
        @foreach(var column in row.Fluctuations)
        {
            <td>@column.Fluctuation</td>
        }
    }
}
```

Then in you controller, loop through you data and build the view model to return to the view.

To solve the issue of creating a new table for each 'group' of sequences, you can create a 'key' based on the 'group' (the `Sequence` property of `TableVM`). If the `Sequence` does not exist yet, add a new `TableVM`, other add a new `TableVM`

To solve the issue of including sequences `ABC` and `ABCD` in the same table, you need a method to identify if the characters in the sequence are sequential (the `IsSequental` property of `TableVM`). If you are really using those characters, then its as simple as

```
private bool IsSequential(string sequence)
{
    char[] c = sequence.ToCharArray();
    return c[0] + c.Length - 1 == c[c.Length - 1];
}
```

although that also suggest an inflexible and fragile design, and you should really consider and `int` property in the database for the sequence/order.

The full code is too much to post in here, but [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LQCRhe) is a working example based on the data you have shown, plus additional data for a sequence `A-B-C-D`. Note I found you table headers a bit confusing and have suggested an alternative in the fiddle.

Comment: This really worked out as expected and 1+ for sequencial logic.Thank you so much and please keep helping like this :)